# How to check if a span in a div contain certain text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

See [my jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sappe/8vr9e30a/22/) where I create a list of span from a dropdown list and I populate an input field.

I would like to don't allow the user to insert the same value over and over (so, if you entered "Galileo Galilei", you can't insert it again if you don't delete if before).

I was trying something like that (right after "var creaIdRimuovi"):

```
var contenutoAttuale = $("#contenitorePersone").text();
if (contenutoAttuale.indexOf(personaSelezionataId) > 0){
    alert("presente"); //just to check if the string is founded
}
```

or also

```
if ("contenutoAttuale:contains('"+personaSelezionataId+"')"){
    alert("presente");
}
```

and both those solution are not working (with the else condition either).

How can I do that? I read that the method contains() is now deprecated, and I'm using the 1.11 in my project.

Comment: For the record it should be: `if (contenutoAttuale.indexOf(personaSelezionataId) >= 0){` where 0 would be the first character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second code example is along the right lines, however the selector needs to be provided to a jQuery object, and you also need to then check the `length` property of that object. Try this:

```
if ($('#contenitorePersone').find('span:contains("' + personaSelezionata + '")').length != 0) {
    alert('presente');
    return;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/8vr9e30a/23/)

The `return` statement exits the event handler function and therefore prevents the new `div` being appended as one already exists.

Answer (score 1):

The logic here is to match the entered value against the value which is already added into below list. So here you go:

```
if(!($('#contenitorePersone').find('span:contains("'+personaSelezionata+'")').length)){

    $('#contenitorePersone').append('<div><span id="span' + personaSelezionataId + '">' + personaSelezionata + '</span> <input type="button" value="-" id=' + creaIdRimuovi + ' class="ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget removeSpan"><br></div>');
    var inputList = $('#personeID').val();
    if ($('#personeID').val() != "") {
      $('#personeID').val(inputList + ", " + personaSelezionataId);
    } else $('#personeID').val(personaSelezionataId);
 }
```

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/Ashokkumargupta/8vr9e30a/24/

Cheers,

Ashok